# How to loop through SQLite step result mutiple times

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way to loop through the same SQLite step result mutiple times.

Scenario:
1. Use step stmt to execute the query
2. Loop thru the result and do some calculation
3. Loop thru the same result and do calculation based on value (2) and print the result.

Can someone please suggest how to do this?

Comment: Don't know any c++ but surely you can save the results in an array, loop through them once, and then loop through them again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not save the entire result of a query; the rows are computed dynamically when you're stepping through the result.

If you want to read the result rows again, you have to re-execute the query (see [`sqlite3_reset`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) and [`sqlite3_step`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)).